# Exception: Failed to load weather data occurred (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, openweathermap

I developed a weather forecast app in Flutter, but when I run it on my cell phone (Android), it shows the error on the screen:

> "Exception: Failed to load weather data occurred";

and in the terminal I get these errors:

> E/ion(18018): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument D/hw-ProcessState(18018): Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed:
> Invalid argument

Code:

weather_model.dart:

```
class WeatherModel {
  final String temp;
  final String city;
  final String desc;

  WeatherModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : temp = json['main']['temp'].toString(),
        city = json['name'],
        desc = json['weather'][0]['description'];
}
```

call_to_api.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:easyweather/constants/api_key.dart';

import 'package:easyweather/logic/models/weather_model.dart';

class CallToApi {
  Future<WeatherModel> callWeatherAPi(bool current, String cityName) async {
    try {
      Position currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition();
  
      if (current) {
        List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
            currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);

        Placemark place = placemarks[0];
        cityName = place.locality!;
      }

      var url = Uri.https('api.openweathermap.org', '/data/2.5/weather',
          {'q': cityName, "units": "metric", "appid": apiKey});
      final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      log(response.body.toString());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);
        return WeatherModel.fromMap(decodedJson);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load weather data');
    }
  }

  Future<Position> getCurrentPosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {

        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
    );
  }
}
```

weather_page.dart:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:anim_search_bar/anim_search_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easyweather/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:easyweather/logic/models/weather_model.dart';
import 'package:easyweather/logic/services/call_to_api.dart';

class WeatherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WeatherPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WeatherPage> createState() => _WeatherPageState();
}

class _WeatherPageState extends State<WeatherPage> {
  Future<WeatherModel> getData(bool isCurrentCity, String cityName) async {
    return await CallToApi().callWeatherAPi(isCurrentCity, cityName);
  }

  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  Future<WeatherModel>? _myData;
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      _myData = getData(true, "");
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If error occured
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  '${snapshot.error.toString()} occurred',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              );

              // if data has no errors
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // Extracting data from snapshot object
              final data = snapshot.data as WeatherModel;
              return Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment(0.8, 1),
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 120, 60, 240), // Rosa
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 144, 255), // Azul Elétrico
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 255), // Ciano
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 0, 128), // Roxo
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 128), // Rosa Choque
                    ],
                    tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                  ),
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      AnimSearchBar(
                        rtl: true,
                        width: 400,
                        color: const Color(0xffffb56b),
                        textController: textController,
                        suffixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 26,
                        ),
                        onSuffixTap: () async {
                          textController.text == ""
                              ? log("No city entered")
                              : setState(() {
                                  _myData = getData(false, textController.text);
                                });

                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                          textController.clear();
                        },
                        style: f14RblackLetterSpacing2,
                        onSubmitted: (String) {},
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              data.city,
                              style: f24Rwhitebold,
                            ),
                            height25,
                            Text(
                              data.desc,
                              style: f16PW,
                            ),
                            height25,
                            Text(
                              "${data.temp}°C",
                              style: f42Rwhitebold,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text("${snapshot.connectionState} occured"),
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Server timed out!"),
          );
        },
        future: _myData!,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easyweather/view/weather_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Easy Weather',

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const WeatherPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Apparently there is nothing wrong with the code, all libraries are updated with the latest version and I am correctly following the use of the API as reported on the official openweather website. Not even ChatGPT can help me...